# How do I establish what IP address has been established for my server

Tags: ubuntu

For school I have to set up an Ubuntu server, I didn't have a clue as to how to go about it, so I followed a guide (video). The problem is that during the guide they demonstrated accessing it using an IP-address with a browser, they used 10.0.2.15, but that address doesn't work for me, so how do I establish what my server's IP address is, so that I can access it via a browser ?

Comment: so what's the problem?

Comment: I can't acces my server via my browser with that IP, unless I'm doing something wrong

Comment: I have edited your question to make it easier for people to answer, please check that I have not changed it, you can [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/118379/edit) it again, if I have. Please take time to phrase your question nicely, then you will get quality answers.

Answer (score 2):

On the server itself you can always use `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` to reach the machine (as part of a URL e.g.).

If the server got its IP address from a router via DHCP, you can see the one it has been given on the server by issuing the command:

```
ifconfig
```

and search for `inet addr` for (normally) `eth0`

Or you can select the GUI applicaton "System Settings" and select Network.

Depending on the router, you can probably also get the IP addresses issued to the various machines via its configuration interface.

Comment: Alternatively one can use `ip addr`. The `/bin/ip` executable will usually be in `$PATH`, even for regular users, while `/sbin/ifconfig` might not.